# mountable engine and modules. how to create lib files in an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I am making an engine for an app that my company will use to do various tasks. My engine needs to use the github_api gem to view and update repositories. While I can access the gem fine with the code in the controller (or in a model), I would like to put these methods in a module in the lib folder, since I will need to connect to another api as well and don't want to clutter my controllers or models with code that shouldn't be there.

But, it seems that my engine doesn't like my module. It doesn't even want to load the file, even when I specify it in the engine.rb file. I put the file inside the engine's lib/modules folder and included the path as it states [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).

My error is as follows:
uninitialized constant MyEngine::WelcomeController::Githubapi

It's like it just won't load my file. And when I try to require it, it gives me errors and won't start the server.

engine.rb

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../lib/modules/", __FILE__)
  end
end
```

githubapi.rb

```
module Githubapi

  # Lists the repository branch names for dropdown-list
  # param[String] repo_name the repository name as GitHub sees it
  def get_repo_branches(repo_name)
    branch_names = Array.new
    git_connection = Github.new :oauth_token => ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']
    branches = git_connection.repos.branches('owner_name',repo_name)
    branches.each do |branch|
      branch_names << branch.name
    end
    branch_names.sort_by!{ |m| m.downcase }
    return branch_names
  end

end
```

calling the method in the controller to pass to the view always results in errors

```
@branches = Githubapi.get_repo_branches('my_repo')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this something that would go in the engine's gemspec using "add_dependency"?

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
[....] stuff [....]
  s.add_dependency "github_api"
[....] stuff [....]
end
```

That's how you signal that your engine uses other gems.